# Webpack 4 + Angular 5 - How to use Rule.parser.system: true

Tags: angular5, webpack-4

I am currently migrating my Angular-webpack 3 application into webpack 4. Everything works fine except two warnings. I searched for the same and the blog below says the you have to use Rule.parser.system: true.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6357

But not able to judge the syntax. Please help.

[warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glZLV.png)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the System.import warning message, add the 'Rule.parser.system: true` like this:

```
module: {
  rules: {
    parser: {
      system: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-parser